# Cannot connect VirtualBox guest to the internet

Tags: virtualbox

I have a Windows 7 host and Ubuntu guest in VirtualBox.

Ubuntu cannot connect to the Internet when my laptop is connected directly via wire to the modem, but when I connect via wireless to the router the VirtualBox guest can connect. The problem therefore only exists when the host is connected via Ethernet cable. Is there any solution to this?

When I'm working with wireless it works but with cable it doesn't. Here are some screenshots showing my config:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing the "Attached to" field in VBox to "NAT". If you use "Bridged" you'd need to specify the 2 ends of the bridge every time, and it would therefore change when your laptop's network adapter changes.

If you want to keep using a briged network, just provide one more adapter binding: i.e.: have Adapter 1 bridge your virtual machine to the Ethernet card and Adapter 2 bridge it to the wireless one.

Comment: Wow! So many problems with bridged option.
NAT works right away! It took literally less than a second to establish client connection. Thanks!